# Coding RSA Algorithm Java

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, biginteger, greatest-common-divisor

So, I am attempting to create an RSA algorithm from scratch.

So far, I have successfully created the ability to select two primes (which I have as 11 and 13 in my current example. Then, I calculate N by doing p x q. Which gets me 143.

Then, I move on to my   `public BigInteger findZ()` method which calculates ϕ which is (p-1)(q-1).

Using this newly calculated ϕ, I want to find a number, or rather create an e variable that follows 1<(e)<ϕ, or simple gcd(e,ϕ) = 1 Thus, I initially set temp to equal my constant ONE (which is equal to one) + 1 to satisfy the range. However, after continuous debugging attempts, the loop never finds a value that has a GCD that is equal to one, which i've created a constant to represent since I am required to use BigInteger. Is there a reason for this?

Here is my code.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class RSA 
{
//Intialize the variables.

private BigInteger p;
private BigInteger q;
private BigInteger n;
private BigInteger z;

final private BigInteger ONE = BigInteger.valueOf(1);


public BigInteger getP()
{
    return p;
}

public BigInteger getQ()
{
    return q;
}

//Computes N, which is just p*q.
public BigInteger findN()
{

    n = p.multiply(q);


    return p.multiply(q);
}


public BigInteger findZ()
{
    long pMinusOne = p.intValue() - 1;
    long qMinusOne = q.intValue() - 1;


    z = BigInteger.valueOf(pMinusOne * qMinusOne);

    return z;
}


public BigInteger getE()
{
     int temp = ONE.intValue() + 1;

     BigInteger GCD = BigInteger.valueOf(temp);

     while (GCD.gcd(z).compareTo(ONE) != 0)
     {
         temp++;
     }



    e = BigInteger.valueOf(temp);

    return e;
}
```

}

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What changes in this code `while (GCD.gcd(z).compareTo(ONE) != 0)
     {
         temp++;
     }`  The only thing that changes is `temp` which is a local variable, so the loop will never end as it does not change

Comment: Well, temp is being changed in the loop, so even though it is being declared locally, it should be changing. Somewhat like indexing in a for loop, correct?

Comment: No, `while (GCD.gcd(z).compareTo(ONE) != 0)` does not use `temp` so changing it makes no difference

Comment: @ScaryWombat Even after removing the temp, changing GDC to be equal to BigInteger.valueOf(2); then looping and doing GCD.add(ONE); until the comparison is true causes the loop to go on forever. So either way there's still no difference.

Comment: I have also tried starting the GCD variable at z-1, however this causes the loop to finish immediately, So my e would always be one less than z, which I believe doesn't work.

Comment: What Scary Wombar is trying to say is that you are comparing `GCD.gcd(z)` to `ONE`, and if that comparison is not zero, you are changing the value of `temp`. But changing the value of `temp` has no effect whatsoever on either of the values you are comparing, so the loop goes on forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you asked for any help, I'll answer your question and give other tips.

## How to get *e*

One tip is to use `equals()` instead of `compareTo()` when you're just checking for equality. Sometimes that can reduce the amount of work being done, and it's easier to read as well.

The biggest error in your code is that `temp` is used to set the original value of `GCD`, but *that doesn't link `temp` to GCD*. They stay disconnected. If you change `temp` later, `GCD` won't know about it and won't change. You need to add one to `GCD` directly. Here's some example code:

```java
BigInteger e = BigInteger.valueOf(3);
while (! phi.gcd(e).equals(BigInteger.ONE)) {
    e = e.add(BigInteger.ONE);
}
```

## Look over `BigInteger`'s methods

Get a sense of what you can easily do with `BigInteger`'s by using your favorite search engine and searching for `BigInteger 8 API`. The 8 is for the version of Java you're using, so that might change. The API is for a list of methods.

Early on in the search results, you should find [this API page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html). `BigInteger` has a lot of nice and convenient methods, so check them out. It even has a constructor that'll give you a `BigInteger` of whatever size you want that's very likely to be a prime, which is nice for generating the primes for a new random RSA key.

## Use `BigInteger`'s built-in constants

Don't recreate the following constants (which show up in the API page above):

- `BigInteger.ZERO`
- `BigInteger.ONE`
- `BigInteger.TEN`

## Never convert `BigInteger` to `long` unless you're sure it'll fit

You're converting `BigInteger`s to `long`, which is a bad idea, since there are a lot of `BigInteger`s that won't fit in a `long`, giving you incorrect results. For correctness (which is more important than speed), *do arithmetic directly with `BigInteger`s*.

You also use `intValue()` a lot when you're getting a `long`. Use `longValueExact()`. For that matter, use `intValueExact()` when you're getting an `int`.

So, to calculate ϕ:

```
BigInteger pMinusOne = p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
BigInteger qMinusOne = q.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);

BigInteger phi = pMinusOne.multiply(qMinusOne);
```

Now you know that it will give correct results, even for larger `BigInteger`s. It's also not that hard to read, which is good for maintaining the code later.

## What to store

You should also store just *n* and *e* (and *d* but only if it's a private key) **Never** store *p*, *q*, or *ϕ* with RSA because those allow you to easily figure out the private key from the public key.

## In general, don't calculate in `getZZZ` methods

You should figure out *n* and *e* (and *d* but only if it's a private key) in the constructor method(s) and store only those in instance variables. Then, you can have a `getN()` and `getE()` method to get the precomputed instance variables. For example (and you don't have to use this code, it's just to give an idea):

```java
public class RSA {
    private final BigInteger n;
    private final BigInteger e;
    private final BigInteger d;

    public RSA(final BigInteger p, final BigInteger q) {
        this.n = p.multiply(q);

        // Calculate phi
        final BigInteger pMinusOne = p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
        final BigInteger qMinusOne = q.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
        final BigInteger phi = pMinusOne.multiply(qMinusOne);

        // Calculate e
        BigInteger e = BigInteger.valueOf(3L);
        while (! phi.gcd(e).equals(BigInteger.ONE)) {
            e = e.add(BigInteger.ONE);
        }
        this.e = e;

        // Calculate d
        this.d = e.modInverse(phi);
    }

    public BigInteger getN() {
        return n;
    }

    public BigInteger getE() {
        return e;
    }

    public BigInteger getD() {
        return d;
    }
}
```

Comment: Phenomenally explained! Thank you so much! This is very helpful. I've never worked with BigInteger until yesterday, so I hadn't looked through the API as thoroughly as I should have.

Comment: My only question is, what is the value of 3L?

Comment: @Granzo Putting `L` after a number means to treat the number as a `long` instead of the default `int`. So, the value of `3L` is just the `long` value `3`. Here, it's unneeded since a `3` (`int`) will be converted just fine to a `3L` (`long`), but I use it out of habit wherever a `long` is expected because a number might overflow without the `L` if it's too large to hold in an `int` and the habit avoids that problem.

Comment: Sorry, final question. When I call to return d, it seems to be returning the incorrect value. For example, i'm testing it with the values of p being 5 and q being 7. However, after calculations im getting that D = 5. Isn't it suppose to be equal to 29?

Comment: Well, yes and no, d = 29 would also work to decrypt things, but phi is 24, so you would always reduce d modulo phi to reduce later computation. Reducing 29 modulo phi, we get 29 ≡ 5 (mod 24), so d = 5 would also work to decrypt, and it takes less time to compute with and (when the numbers get bigger), less space to store.